# s4 mini SD card makes battery drains fast?

Tags: sd-card

I have inserted a 8GB SD Card in my S4 mini i9190 and since then only GPS enabled my phone loss abt 5% per hour battery. For me it is a big shock to only last a day at best as usually my old phone which is way smaller last for 2 days on battery...really awful but if I remove the SD Card and use the replacement battery got from MPJ, the battery life is awesome.
Is the SD Card fautly or something wrong with my phone??

Comment: You mention that you removed the SD card AND used another battery, but how is the battery life with the replacement battery and the SD card inserted?

Comment: Likewise, you have GPS on - how is it with SD card and each battery and GPS off? How is is without the card and with GPS on and each battery? You have to look at things changing one at a time, and comparing the same things with one thing changed in order to make any sense of them from what changes. Best bet right now looks to be bad "original" battery, good "replacement" battery...but it's impossible to be sure when you change several things at once. On my phone, GPS is a power hog (it assumes a connection to vehicle power, I think) and is not good to leave on when not actively using it.

Answer (score 2):

There are known issues with certain SD cards causing some read/write errors which prevent your phone from entering the deep sleep state. This causes your phone to drain battery fairly quickly as compared to a phone which goes into deep sleep when not in use.

You should update your phone as certain kernels have also been known to fix battery drain issues. If it doesn't help, consider changing to another sd card from another manufacturer.